# Regex - Match string with or without suffix, but without including it in match group

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to make a text message command server (basically, I send a text to google voice, that gets forwarded to my email, I use a python IMAP library to access the message, and I parse it), and I have an interesting problem. Sometimes, when a text comes through, the string

```
--
Sent using SMS-to-email. Reply to this email to text the sender back and save on SMS fees.
https://www.google.com/voice/
```

is appended to the text message, which causes errors when parsing the command. Right now, to detect commands, I use the following regex (which is multiline and case-sensitive due to certain commands such as a timed send command that may use multiple lines):

```
^/(randomfact) *(\S*)\s*$
```

But since the string telling me it was sent through SMS to email comes through once in a while, a match doesn't get detected. Using the `print` function of python, the message is shown as follows:

```
/randomfact\r\n\r\n--\r\nSent using SMS-to-email. Reply to this email to text the sender back and  \r\nsave on SMS fees.\r\nhttps://www.google.com/voice/
```

Right now, to combat that issue, I have tried doing this:

```
^/(randomfact)\s*(\d*)(?=\n\n--\nSent using SMS-to-email\. Reply to this email to text the sender back and save on SMS fees\.\nhttps://www\.google\.com/voice/)
```

But it only works if the string IS appended to the command. If it isn't, then the regex fails. My question is: Is there any way to exclude that string from any regex matches, whether it exists in the string or not?

Comment: So you just need a way to filter out the footer that occasionally appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def remove_footer(incoming_str):
    footer = '''
--
Sent using SMS-to-email. Reply to this email to text the sender back and save on SMS fees.
https://www.google.com/voice/'''
    if incoming_str[-len(footer):] == footer:
        return incoming_str[:-len(footer)]
    else:
        return incoming_str
```

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: I think this is the best idea for what I am trying to do. Using regular expression would just cause more issues

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are filtering out the optional signature of the message. In python you should be able to set the single line regex flag (i.e. `re.S`), and use the following regex to capture the desired content.

```
regex = re.compile(r'(.+)(?=--)|(.+)', r.S)
```

Comment: This would be great, however, certain commands may be multiline, for example a /send command (which sends a message at a scheduled time), would accept multiline inputs, which I can parse, except for that footer. I will update the main post.

Comment: When you say "certain commands may be multiline", are you saying that the body of your message may contain newline characters? `re.S` allows the `.` metacharacter to match `\n` characters. Have you tried the supplied regex? Or is there some other aspect to your problem that I'm missing?

Comment: Because a certain command may have newlines, and accepts user input, I can't assume that the user won't enter two dashes.

Comment: You have a few options in my opinion then. You can add specificity to the regex look-around (e.g. `(?=--\nSent using)`) or you can leave the specificity as is, and understand the limitations of your inputs (e.g. users cannot enter `--`. A large part of using regexes is understanding your inputs. The signature seems to be a constant, so it seems safe to match it character-for-character and rely up that. It's brittle, but it will work until the signature changes.